# Vue.js 2.0 Multi-step Wizard

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am working on a multi-step wizard using Vue.js 2.0.

I have based this on an example I found using vue 1.0.26.

I have updated the code and think it is 90% there but can't figure out how to fix it, here is a snippet of my code

```
data: {
    currentstep : 1,
    indicatorclass: true,
    step: 1,
    active: 1,
    firststep: 1,
    nextStep: 2,
    lastStep: 0,
    laststep: 3,
    steps: [
        { 
            id: 1, 
            title: 'Position', 
            icon_class: "fa fa-map-marker" 
        }, { 
            id: 2, 
            title: 'Category', 
            icon_class: "fa fa-folder-open" 
        }, { 
            id: 3, 
            title: 'Send', 
            icon_class: "fa fa-paper-plane" 
        }
    ]
},
```

The full project can be seen [here](http://codepen.io/jonnyfoley/pen/rjwLjQ). You can see that it walks through the steps, but throws a mutation error. There must be something else wrong, as well, as the step indicator is showing below when it shouldn't (and wrongly at that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. Move your templates outside the rest of the HTML. They are not part of the document flow. For me, that got rid of the extraneous step indicator.
2. Instead of modifying the prop in your event emit:

   ```
   this.$emit('step-change', ++this.currentstep)
   ```

   send the new value as a computation:

   ```
   this.$emit('step-change', this.currentstep + 1)
   ```

   so you're not mutating the prop.

Comment: Thank you Roy, makes perfect sense now and this solved both my issues! Updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jonnyfoley/pen/rjwLjQ) and moved the templates from the HTML into the JS as well.

Comment: Any idea how this would look if the wizard contains form fields which need to be filled before moving to the next step?

Comment: @Mike I expect the Next button would have a binding to set it to disabled until the form fields are filled.

Comment: @RoyJ yeah but, the next button must have a binding do different fields depending on the position inside the wizard.

Comment: @Mike Sure, you have to model it somehow. I'd create a method `currentStepIsValid` that controls the button's disabled status. I know the current step, and I know what it requires, so I could implement that.